# Django HttpResponse does not redirect after Javascript Post with fetch

Tags: javascript, django

With the following Post using Javascript

```
    function send_dialog() {
        fetch('dialog', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id_to_dialog
            })

        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            // Print result
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
```

and the corresponding function of the django view:

```
     @csrf_exempt
     def dialog(request):
            print(request)
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            print(data)
            return HttpResponse("HEY")
```

I'm able to print out the data, but the website doesn't get redirected to the simple page showing "Hey".

So far I've tried several other methods reverse, redirect etc. from django, but could never successfully redirect to the "hey" page.

Comment: what makes you think there will be any redirection here? All your JS code does is logs the response - in this case "HEY" - to the browser console. If you see that then this code is working as presumably intended.

Comment: If you're trying to send the user to that page, then you need a `<a href="dialog">` in your HTML rather than (what I presume is) a button that calls this function. Or if you really must do it in JS code for some reason then you do `window.location = "dialog"`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you. I'm just a newbie and now used to use "djangos post forms, with a redirect". Right now I'm using a dynamic page to generate some json data with javascript. I would like to send this data to another page without even storing it inside a database so that I can access the data via javascript on the page after redirection.